# Google cloud messaging: registration_ids vs. device group

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

When should I prefer sending a message to a [device group](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications#managing_device_groups) over a list of registration ids ([a message with registration_ids parameter](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#send-downstream))?

It's seems like managing device groups only adds complexity. For device group the app server should contain logic for when to create a group or just add a registration id. The server still needs to save the registration ids in some database and in addition it now needs to save the notification key. The [responses](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications#http_response) seem less detailed: the reason for failures is not specified, so it's harder to know what should be done in order to prevent the failure (was the app uninstalled? is the registration token expired? etc.).
What am I missing? What are the benefits?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`Registration_ids` and `Device Group` can be tricky and be use on the developer’s choice. Sending a message using registration ID according to this [guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream):

> In this context, "simple" means messages sent from the app server to a
>   client app on a device, as opposed to routing messages through topics
>   or device groups.

For [Device Group](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications):

> With device group messaging, app servers can send a single message to multiple instance of an app running on devices belonging to a group. Typically, "group" refers a set of different devices that belong to a single user. However, a group could also represent a set of devices where the app instance functions in a highly correlated manner, such as a phone with a temperature control app installed, a smart thermostat, and an automatic window opener. All devices in a group share a common notification key, which is the token that GCM uses to fan out messages to all devices in the group.

Based on this sending single message with list of register_ID is for a more straight forward approach, simple coding and less complexity with managing of keys. While Device group handles complex list of registered devices (single user with multiple devices registered in the server) using device group would be more rationale to use.

*NOTE*: check the server if it can handle the queries of these messaging types.

Comment: Why using device group for a single user with multiple devices is the rationale choice? What is the benefit over a list of registration ids? The registration ids are saved and managed on the app server anyway

Answer (score 0):

Device groups are mainly used for users who have multiple devices running the same app, thus all belonging to the same device group. Some of the benefits of these include:

**Notification sync:** You could implement some cool features that can sync notifications together such as one a notification is cancelled on one device that same notification will disappear on their other devices. Or when one device presses a notification, the details of the device, the state of the app, configurations, etc can be sent to all other devices and perhaps the others can be adjusted accordingly.

**Less Microhandling:** I do believe that when a user uninstalls or gets a new token ID for their device that the device group will automatically adjust to not send to that device anymore. Thus, if a user uninstalls an app, you won't have to update that list of IDs to delete their token. You still would have to delete from your main server database though.

**Easier to differentiate**You could make every single user, even if they only have one device, belong in their own device group. This makes it easier such that when picking distinct users to send notifications to, you don't have to dig up users and dig up all their associated IDs, just dig up their notification key and FCM will handle the rest.

Of course these are pretty specific use cases, but I'm sure there's a lot more you could do with notification sync-ing depending on what kind of app you wanna use.